# Active/selected row in grid.js?

Tags: javascript, gridjs

We need a grid control in our web application, and we are looking into grid.js. (I’m new to grid.js, so sorry if this is a dumb question. )

Grid.js handle most of our needs – and an MIT license is great! But I’m missing one feature.

We need to handle the concept of an “active row” in the grid. I don’t mean selecting rows with checkboxes – that is supported by grid.js. But that we can set one row as active/selected, rendered in a special color. The user should be able to click on a row to select it – and move the selection with the arrow keys. When the user selects a different row, an event should be fired that we could catch.

Many grid components support this, but I haven’t found anything about it in the grid.js documentation. Am I just missing something? Or do we need to add some plugin? Or do you have any other smart solution?

/Anders from Sweden